# Cannot Get Twitter Bootstrap Modal to Work

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I cant seem to get my modal working. I get the transparent overlay to show, but that is it. The content is there in a `<div>`, but wont show up in a modal format on the screen. Here is my code. Does anyone have any ideas?

Here is my HTML:

```
<a href="#modal-[nid]" class="ajax-link" data-nid="[nid]" 
  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-[nid]">[title]</a>
<div id="modal-[nid]" class="modal hide" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-body">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" 
          aria-hidden="true">×</button>
        <span>this is a test of my modal</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have never tried to implement anything like this before. I have the bootstrap CSS files loaded and the JS files. Does anyone have any ideas where I am going wrong?

**---EDIT---**

My exit button is not working and is looking like this:

[image]

It does not seem to be loading the button in the html... just shows an `x` with no `<button>` tags around it.

Comment: do you have a working environment that we can see? this is kind of like saying my car wont start but its got petrol in it...

Comment: reference --> http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals or make a working demo of your code at http://bootply.com

Comment: I assume the code above is a template file and [nid] is being replaced by a variable on your live site? Have you tried replacing [nid] temporarily with a static name and see if it works? You've also missed out quite a lot of the HTML that the Bootstrap Docs show in the modal example. I'm not exactly sure how much is required but maybe try duplicating their code first to see if you can get it to work: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few things wrong. Take out the `hide` class. Wrap the body inside a `modal-content` and that inside a `modal-dialog`

```
<a href="#modal-1" class="ajax-link" data-nid="[nid]" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-1">[title]</a>
  <div id="modal-1" class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-body">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" 
            aria-hidden="true">×</button>
          <span>this is a test of my modal</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

http://www.bootply.com/124339

Comment: This does seem to get the modal to show. But that close buttone does not seem to work. I updated my question with a picture of what is happening. I would like to completely change the `x` button to a image anyway. Would you happen to have any ideas with what class or attributes I need to add to accomplish this?